# How parse JS Date to be consistent in all browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, cross-browser

I'm hanging on a problem for a while now and can't figure it out.

The problem:

I have this date string: `2015-08-25T08:00:00Z`

I'm trying to parse this String into a JS Date: `var date = new Date( date_string );`

If I log this:
- Chrome: `Tue Aug 25 2015 10:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`
- Safari: `Tue Aug 25 2015 10:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`
- Firefox: `Date 2015-08-25T08:00:00.000Z` **(Why is Firefox showing a different time than the other browsers?)**

But i want them all to show the Date I parse.
The other thing is: I don't want the string to be affected by the timezone.
Result schould be in all browsers a date with the date of the string.

Also tried to parse with `moment.js` but even that didn't solve my problem.

Thank you!!

Comment: Try moment.js - it will make this 100x less stressful 

Comment: I did, but I had the same problem with the timezone offset.

Comment: Yeah you might for sure, just that parsing it with moment is a little more concise - and you can use the same tz offset stuff.

Comment: @remus: there's nothing wrong with the parsing, that's mandated by the ecma spec, so all browsers do it the same; there's no need for a lib to get uniformity on parsing std date formats... now, if you want to format dates or parse weird formats, then yes, moment can save a lot of legwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out myself.

If I log this:

```
console.log( date.getHours() );
```

The output is the same in all browsers.

To get rid of the timezone stuff if did:

```
var date = new Date( date_string );
date = new Date( date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours() );
```

But can someone tell me, why firefox is displaying something else, then the other browsers, even when its the same object?

Comment: the parsing is fine and 100% the same everywhere, it's just the console output formatting that varies. the formatting of the date object as a string is implementation specific,not mandated by the spec. no right or wrong on this opinion of what it should look like, though a lot of folks do complain about FF in particular. i prefer to use a re-offset ISOString() and the replace the "T" to get a consistent output in all browsers. its a pain, but it's also a one-line fix that needs no libs.